# How to use cx_freeze in Windows to create a package to be used in Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I am using Python31 and cx_freeze to create executables on Windows machine. The executables work perfectly on all Windows systems. But they do not run on Linux. What changes should I do in my setup.py file? The one I'm using is:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includes1 = list()
path1 = sys.path[:]
package=list()

executables = [Executable("D:\MyCode\MyFile.py")]
buildOptions = dict(\
        includes = includes1,\
        path = path1,\
        packages = package)

setup(  name = "NAME",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "DESCRIPTION",
        options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
        executables = executables)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a Linux executable, you need to freeze it in Linux. To create a Mac executable, you need to freeze it on a Mac. That's the way cx_Freeze works, and there isn't an option you can use to build executables for other platforms.

If you make a Windows executable, Linux users might be able to run it with [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/). But that's a workaround, and there's no guarantee that it will work.